# grep result get separated by spaces when saving it to variable

Tags: bash, shell

need your help on this. I have a simple XML file goes like:

```
<Entity ID="12345" Record="1">
<Info>
    <Type>Individual</Type>
    <Name>Test</Name>
</Info>
```

```
<Entity Record="2">
<Info>
    <Type>Individual</Type>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
</Info>
```

And what I want to do is to grep the attributes and its value for the  node.

This is my code:

```
entities=($(grep -oP '(?<=<Entity ).*(?=>)' "abc.xml"))
for j in ${!entities[*]}
do
echo "${entities[$j]}"
((count++))
done
echo "Total Count: $count"
```

Ouput:

```
ID="12345"
Record="1"
Record="2"
Total Count: 3
```

However, my desired result is supposed to be:

```
ID="12345" Record="1"
Record="2"
Total Count: 2
```

When I save the grep result to a variable, it somehow get separated whenever there is a space. Wondering if anyone could help me on this, thank you in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't use `grep` to parse html/xml and other markup languages. A proper tool for what you want to to would be `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Also, you issue is caused because `echo` by default outputs a newline. Try `echo -n` or `printf` to output text without a newline.

Comment: Provide a syntactically valid XML first

Comment: @Aserre I tried, it also return me the same result, but instead of newline, I am getting it in one single line ID="12345"Record="1"Record="2"Total Count: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your IFS is wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash
ifs_ini="$IFS"

IFS=$'\n'
entities=( $(grep -oP '(?<=<Entity ).*(?=>)' "abc.xml") )
for j in ${!entities[@]}; do
    echo "${entities[$j]}"
    ((count++))
done
echo "Total Count: $count"

IFS="$ifs_ini"
```

output:

```
ID="12345" Record="1"
Record="2"
Total Count: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest to use an XML parser, for example you could use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Now assuming this is your valid XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
    <Entity ID="12345" Record="1">
        <Info>
            <Type>Individual</Type>
            <Name>Test</Name>
        </Info>
    </Entity>
    <Entity ID="123456" Record="1">
        <Info>
            <Type>Individual</Type>
            <Name>Test</Name>
        </Info>
    </Entity>
</foo>
```

To extract the fields something for starting could be:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m //Entity -o ID= -v "@ID" -o " Redcord=" -v "@Record" -n your.xml
```

This will print:

```
ID=12345 Redcord=1
ID=123456 Redcord=1
```

To count the number of elements:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "count(//Entity)" your.xml
```

These are just the basics but hope it can help you to get an idea.